# I can not test iOS 7.0.3 device on Xcode 5.0.1

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I have iOS 7.0.3 device. I plug in to my computer and Xcode does not recognise my device. But i plug in iOS 6.0.1 device to computer and i can run on device.
How can i test iOS 7.0.3 device ?

Comment: "does not recognize my device", do you mean it doesn't show on the list on the upper bar of xcode (where you can select the simulator mode to use to test), or does it also not appear on organizer ? (Window => Organizer => (Devices tab) If it appears on this second location, select it and check if you don't need to put it in developer mode.

Comment: Which OS you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connect the 7.0.3 device, open organizer in xcode (shift+cmd+1), go to tha devices tab and click "use for development" to make the device a development device.

Answer (score -1):

I think Xcode has a bugs. My device is using iOS 7.0.3, it works fine. Can you reset the Xcode, quite simulator and build it again ? If No, please res install your Xcode.